# ternary conditional operators in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am working quite a bit with terraform in hopes of building an in-house solution to standing up infra.  So far, I have written most of the terraform code and am building out the Ansible code for post-processing of the instances that are stood up.  I am shuttling over the dynamic inventory from terraform to Ansible using this little Go app that can be found here, https://github.com/adammck/terraform-inventory.  All of that works well.

As I get more into the terraform code, I am trying to use a ternary conditional operator on the ssh key for Linux instances.  The goal is to "reuse" this resource on multiple instances.

My resource looks like this ..

```
resource "aws_key_pair" "key" {
  key_name = var.ssh_key
  count = var.create_ssh_key ? 1 : 0
  public_key = file("~/.ssh/${var.ssh_key}")
}
```

I've included the [count.index] within the key argument here ...

```
resource "aws_instance" "linux" {
  ami           = var.linux_ami
  instance_type = var.linux_instance_type
  count         = var.linux_instance_number
  subnet_id     = data.aws_subnet.itops_subnet.id
  key_name      = aws_key_pair.key[count.index].key_name
  ...
```

`$ terraform validate` comes back clean.

`$ terraform plan -var-file response-file.tfvars -var "create_ssh_key=false"` does not.

The std error is as follows ...

```
$ terraform plan -var-file response-file.tfvars -var "create_ssh_key=false"
╷
│ Error: Invalid index
│
│   on instances.tf line 16, in resource "aws_instance" "linux":
│   16:   key_name      = aws_key_pair.key[count.index].key_name
│     ├────────────────
│     │ aws_key_pair.key is empty tuple
│     │ count.index is 0
│
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
```

What am I missing?

Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 2):

if `count` in `aws_key_pair` is 0, there is no key to reference later on at all.

So you have to check for that and use `null` to eliminate `key_name` in such a case:

```
resource "aws_instance" "linux" {
  ami           = var.linux_ami
  instance_type = var.linux_instance_type
  count         = var.linux_instance_number
  subnet_id     = data.aws_subnet.itops_subnet.id
  key_name      = var.create_ssh_key ? aws_key_pair.key[0].key_name : null
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the root problem in your example here is that your `resource "aws_key_pair" "key"` block and your `resource "aws_instance" "linux"` block both have different values for `count`, and so therefore it isn't valid to use the `count.index` of the second to access an instance of the first.

In your case, you seem to have zero key pairs (it says `aws_key_pair.key is empty tuple`) but you have at least one EC2 instance, and so your expression is trying to access the zeroth instance of the key pair resource, which then fails because it doesn't have a zeroth instance.

If you are using Terraform v0.15 or later then you can use [the `one` function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/one.html) to concisely handle both the zero- and one-instance cases of the key pair resource, like this:

```
resource "aws_instance" "linux" {
  # ...
  key_name = one(aws_key_pair.key[*].key_name)
  # ...
}
```

Breaking this down into smaller parts:

- `aws_key_pair.key[*].key_name` is a [splat expression](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/splat.html) which projects from the list of objects `aws_key_pair.key` into a list of just strings containing key names, by accessing `.key_name` on each of the objects. In your case, because your resource can only have count 0 or 1, this'll be either a zero-or-one-element list of key names.
- `one` then accepts both of those possible results as follows:

  - If it's a one-element list, it'll return just that single element no longer wrapped in a list.
  - If it's a zero-element list, it'll return `null` which, in a resource argument, means the same thing as not specifying that argument at all.

The effect, then, will be that if you have one key pair then it'll associate that key pair, but if you have *no* key pairs then it'll leave that argument unset and thus create an instance that doesn't have a key pair at all.